# iTunes Purchase Without Download

Tags: itunes, applications

Is there a way to purchase an app from the App Store using iTunes without having to download it?  I'm thinking like a hidden preference/mouse/modifier key during click, etc.

I know the download can be canceled, but what I'm asking is if there is a way to prevent the download all together...

[image: Example Download After Purchase]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean exactly and what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MattLove When you buy an app from the App Store through iTunes (and through iOS or the Mac App Store, for that matter), it begins to download immediately. I believe the OP wants his purchase to be processed, but for the app to *not* be downloaded, until some later time. (And I'm not aware of any way to do so.)

Comment: I've updated the question a little in an attempt to clarify the question and I added an image showing the current behavior of iTunes.

Answer (score 3):

No. You need to manually cancel the download upon purchase.

Comment: My issue with cancelling the download is that it 'stalks' you in the downloads section of the store.  Even if you delete it after pausing it, it will be an available download.  This does not happen with apps that are downloaded and then deleted.

Comment: @BennettDill Aren't you going to download the app eventually?

Answer (score 2):

You could always simply Gift This App to someone (e.g., yourself). This works especially well when you're not on WiFi and want to buy an app that's over 20MB or when you want to buy an app during a sale.

Comment: I was excited for this option, but I'm not seeing Gift this App as an option on free apps :-(

Comment: can't gift a free app. only apps for purchase.